# Find number of observations until a specific word is found

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Say I have the following `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
    ID = rep(c(1,2,3),4), 
    day = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3),rep(4,3)),
    Status = c(rep('A',3),'A','B','B','A','C','B','A','D','C')
)
```

What I would like to achieve is that for each `ID`, find number of observations (in this case if sorted by `days`, the number of `day` it takes to hit a specific `Status`. So if I need to do this for `Status C`, the result would be:

`0` for `ID 1` (since doesn't contain status C), `3` for `ID 2`, and `4` for `ID 3`.

The only way came to my mind was to write a function and do nested `for loops`, but I am sure there should be much better/faster/more efficient ways.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I couldn't follow. Why for status C  result is 3 for ID2? And ID3 is 4? There is only one observation  for each ID but you mentioned number of observations. Do you mean the day number corresponding to the status? But if this is the case,  what will the expected output for status A?

Comment: Can you please share a sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

DT %>% left_join(
  DT %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(col = row_number()[Status == 'C'])
) %>% replace_na(list(col= 0))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID'. You can override using the
`.groups` argument.
Joining, by = "ID"
    ID day Status col
 1:  1   1      A   0
 2:  2   1      A   3
 3:  3   1      A   4
 4:  1   2      A   0
 5:  2   2      B   3
 6:  3   2      B   4
 7:  1   3      A   0
 8:  2   3      C   3
 9:  3   3      B   4
10:  1   4      A   0
11:  2   4      D   3
12:  3   4      C   4
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible `data.table` approach adding one column for the number of days to reach each `status` (0 if never reached):

```
library(data.table)

## status id's 
status_ids <- unique(DT$Status)
status_cols <- paste("status", status_ids, sep = "_")

## add one column for each status id
setorder(DT, ID, day)
DT[, (status_cols) := lapply(status_ids, \(s) ifelse(any(Status == s), min(day[Status == s]), 0)), by = "ID"]
     
DT
#>     ID day Status status_A status_B status_C status_D
#>  1:  1   1      A        1        0        0        0
#>  2:  1   2      A        1        0        0        0
#>  3:  1   3      A        1        0        0        0
#>  4:  1   4      A        1        0        0        0
#>  5:  2   1      A        1        2        3        4
#>  6:  2   2      B        1        2        3        4
#>  7:  2   3      C        1        2        3        4
#>  8:  2   4      D        1        2        3        4
#>  9:  3   1      A        1        2        4        0
#> 10:  3   2      B        1        2        4        0
#> 11:  3   3      B        1        2        4        0
#> 12:  3   4      C        1        2        4        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` by `ID` and return the first `match` of day.

```
sapply(split(DT[,2:3], DT$ID), \(x) x$day[match("C", x$Status)])
# 1  2  3 
#NA  3  4
```